# What does Rick mean when he says "When it comes to women, you're a true democrat"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, casablanca

In the movie [*Casablanca*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034583/) (my all-time fave), Rick (Humphrey Bogart) remarks to Captain Renault (the Prefect of Police) during one scene: "When it comes to women, you're a true democrat." I've always been puzzled as to what in the world that means. It seems that if I had been alive and politically active during the 1940s when the film was made, I would have understood it.

Here's the full exchange:

> Renault: Hello, Rick.
>
> Rick: Hello, Louis.
>
> Renault: How extravagant you are, throwing away women like that.
>   Someday they may be scarce. I think now I shall pay a call on Yvonne.
>   Maybe get her on the rebound.
>
> Rick: When it comes to women, you're a true democrat.

Any ideas?

Comment: democrat or Democrat?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's just a play on the idea of social equality. The gist is that Louis loves the company of all women equally.

Comment: I got here because the SE algorithm linked this Rick to Rick and Morty Rick.

Comment: Possibly: Louis is egalitarian toward women in that he treats them all equally shabbily.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I don't think it is about being "liberal" so much as having "democratic" beliefs. To say someone is democratic means they believe in equal representation. By calling Renault a "true democrat", Rick is saying that Renault is indiscriminate with his choice of women. All women are equal in his eyes, not politically but sexually. Renault doesn't have a type, he'll pursue any girl. When one jilts him, he moves on smoothly to another. It suggests his pursuit of all women is akin to a political ideology, which really means Renault doesn't have an ideology at all: he's just an opportunistic hedonist.

But I think that there's a little more going on. Rick is an American and is probably attached to democracy as an ideal. Meanwhile, decidedly undemocratic ideologies like Nazism and Fascism are warring with democratic nations to determine which philosophy will win out. By calling Renault a "true democrat" while living in the colony of an occupied "democratic" country, Rick may also be making a wry statement about what little power dissidents have.

Answer (score 10):

This has absolutely nothing to do with the American political party of that name. Here, *democrat* (and not *Democrat*) is used in its [regular meaning](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/democrat) (either 1, or more likely, 2 of the definitions below):

> 1. an advocate of democracy.
> 2. a person who believes in the political or social equality of all people.
> 3. (initial capital letter) Politics. a member of the Democratic Party. a member of the Democratic-Republican Party.
> 4. Also called democrat wagon. a high, lightweight, horse-drawn wagon, usually having two seats.

The movie Casablanca is set in 1941, in the Moroccan city of Casablanca. At the time, Casablanca was ["under the dual control of Nazi Germany and the Nazi-puppet government in Vichy, France, that the Germans had installed after occupying France in 1940"](http://historylessons.net/newspaper-columns/casablanca). The Prefect of Police, therefore, was the Prefect of Police of a fascist state, the very antithesis of a democracy. He was a member of the executive branch of a fascist government.

Therefore, the line you are asking about is making a point about precisely that. Although, despite his personal political positions, Captain Renault is the arm of the Fascist government, when it comes to women, he is a true democrat: a person who believes in the political or social equality of all people. Or, more likely, one who believes in the "right" of any and all women to end up in his bed.

Answer (score 3):

Rick is an American [expatriate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expatriate).  A Democrat (at least in America) is a member of the Democratic party, which is the liberal party in US politics.

Another definition for the word [*liberal*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liberal) is "not bound by authoritarianism, orthodoxy, or traditional forms."

So, by calling him a "true Democrat" in regards to women, he's suggesting that Renault is a womanizer; someone who is "not bound by traditional forms."  ie: he sleeps around a lot.  This is prompted by Renault's earlier statement about paying a visit to Yvonne on the basis that "someday they [women] might be scarce."  (To say the least, a flimsy excuse if ever there was one.)

Comment: Your answer beat mine by 36 seconds; mine adds nothing.  +1 and removing mine.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what platform points looked like back then. The Democrats were definitely more of the party of labor, even then, but they were also the party of entrenched Jim Crowe, so it might be interesting to see how liberal/conservative the main parties were at the time.  Also, there were a lot more moderates and even conservative Democrats and liberal Republicans than we see today.

Comment: I'm not sure that I buy this answer; I always thought that line meant simply that, just as democracies allow anyone to vote regardless of their knowledge of the issues, Renault sees all women as targets regardless of their individual differences. I never thought of it as a commentary on American partisan politics.

Comment: I thought in the 40s the Democrats were considered the more conservative party, and the Republicans the more Liberal party?

Comment: I didn't intend to say that politics played a role in the metaphor, only that Democrat == Liberal.  Then change gears, to use a second definition of "liberal" which is entirely non-political.

Comment: This answer is wrong. He's using "democrat" with a lower case d to mean "one with the people," or that he takes all women. It has nothing to do with the political parties in the United States at the time.

Comment: I thought it meant he doesn't discriminate based on class--i.e. he'll sleep with rich and poor women.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Democrats, he was called a *democrat* not a *Democrat*. I don't see why this would have anything whatsoever to do with the political party of the same name.

Answer (score -2):

I believe this account has nothing to do with sexual equality.  It is clearly a slam against Renault acting in an unscrupulous way toward a vulnerable woman on the 'rebound'. Rick is a Republican evidently since he fights wars against socialists and fascists, now pointing in sarcastic tone to Renaults' weakness, i. e. Seeing another persons weakness and seeking self gratification easily in a woman unbalanced and easily dominated.  Renault does this during the film, being told by his servant that a particular woman was needing help, waiting outside his office.  He spruces up before the mirror.  Obvious predator, using his power in office to 'trade' favors for an exit visa. It is this dictatorial power over a woman in weak position that Rick is predicating against.  He fights for the little guy by nature, but in Casablanca he himself has been wounded and is off balance until his relationship is healed with Ilsa.

Comment: Can you tell us *why* this is your take on it? This seems to be an unfounded rant, and will likely get deleted.